# How to make a point's position time-dependent given a formula for the next step?

Tags: vector

I've made a program that is just some points on a plane. Red points are cops and green points are robbers. Each point has a vector indicating where it is going to be in the next step of $t$. Right now $t = 0$ but I want to see what happens when $t=1,2,3,\ldots$

Here is a picture:

[image]

The points are in this list. `rob[i]` and `cop[i]` make random pairs of x-y cordinates:

```
r = Table[rob[i], {i, 1, n}],
c = Table[cop[i], {i, 1, m}]
```

The next position are given by the formulae:

```
Table[r[[i]] + Normalize@Sum[(r[[i]] - c[[j]])/Norm[r[[i]] - c[[j]]]^2, {j, 1,Length[c]}],{i,1,Length[r]}]
```

and

```
Table[c[[i]] + Normalize@ Sum[(r[[i]] - c[[j]])/Norm[r[[i]] - c[[j]]]^2,{j, 1,Length[r]}],{i,1,Length[c]}]
```

for robbers and cops, respectively. I want to do something like add a parameter $t$ and when that parameter changes the next position of the points should be updated by the above formulae.

Thanks for helping.

**EDIT:**

Using the answer of asterix314 I came accross this:

[image]

Comment: Please check the formula for the next position of cops. Should the formula be symmetric for robbers and cops?

Comment: All formulas are actually valid, also what do you mean by symetric?

Comment: Wow, beautiful. So the cops are really chasing after the robbers! But if you look at the definition of `r[t]` and `c[t]` in my code, they are symmetric meaning they are defined the same way but with `r` and `c` switched. So the robbers should chase after the cops also. Your formula is not strictly symmetric (opposite sign). Also in the second one for `c`, the iterator inside `Sum` should be `j` instead of `i`?

Comment: The robber in the upper-right corner first takes a U-turn and then quickly turns right to run away from the 2 cops. How exciting!

Comment: @asterix314 Yeah you're absolutely right, the iterator inside sum should be j instead of i, so if it's a cop the correct next[] would be: Normalize@Sum[c[t][[i]]-r[t]/...], if it's a robber, Normalize@Sum[r[t][[j]]-c[t]/...]. Just change the r[0] and c[0] position, in all parts of the formula. i=length[c[t],j=length[c[t]]. I guess this explains it all.

Comment: Indeed. Robbers and cops should have opposite signs of the next step. And I have modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Looking at your animation, I'm thinking perhaps the time $t$ could be made continuous and one may instead solve some simultaneous ODE's ...

Comment: @asterix314 Please would you mind if you tell some hints about where to start solving those equations? You only have a next position's vector, how do you implement that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if we made time continuous? The discrete formulae transform to a system of differential equations:

$$
\mathbf{r_i}'(t) = \text{Normalize@}\sum_j{\frac{\mathbf{r_i}(t)-\mathbf{c_j}(t)}{{|\mathbf{r_i}(t)-\mathbf{c_j}(t)|}^2}}
$$

$$
\mathbf{c_i}'(t) = -\text{Normalize@}\sum_j{\frac{\mathbf{c_i}(t)-\mathbf{r_j}(t)}{{|\mathbf{c_i}(t)-\mathbf{r_j}(t)|}^2}}
$$

Some observations:

- The direction of a robber is determined by averaging the direction of all robber-cop pairs, weighted by the inverse of distance (dominated by the nearest cop).
- Robbers run away from the cops, and cops run towards the robbers, thus the opposite signs of velocity.
- The magnitude of velocity is always 1 for both robbers and cops (`Normalize`d). This means robbers will never be caught.

`NDSolve` can solve for complex numbers which we'll use to represent the planar points. To keep the robbers from running too far away, 4 additional guarding cops (who remain invisible) are placed on the sides of a 2x2 square.

```
solveChase[cops_Integer, robbers_Integer, duration_Integer, opts: OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Module[{b, v, c, r, s, t},
        (* guards on the 4 sides to keep robbers fromm running away. *)
        b[z_] := {Re[z] + I, Re[z] - I, 1 + Im[z] I, -1 + Im[z] I};
        (* direction of velocity *)
        v[z_, g_List] := Normalize@Sum[(z - g[[i]])/Abs[z - g[[i]]]^2, {i, Length[g]}];
        s = NDSolve[Join[
            Table[r[i]'[t] == v[r[i][t], b[r[i][t]]~Join~Array[c[#][t] &, cops]], {i, robbers}],
            Table[c[i]'[t] == -v[c[i][t], Array[r[#][t] &, robbers]], {i, cops}],
            (* initial positions *)    
            Thread[Array[r[#][0] &, robbers] == RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, robbers]],
            Thread[Array[c[#][0] &, cops] == RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, cops]]], 
            Array[c, cops]~Join~Array[r, robbers],
            {t, 0, duration}, 
            FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NDSolve]]];
        {Array[c, cops], Array[r, robbers]} /. s // First]
```

Let's try

```
cops = 8;
robbers = 10;
duration = 5;
Clear[r, c]
Evaluate@{Array[c, cops], Array[r, robbers]} =
    solveChase[cops, robbers, duration, PrecisionGoal -> 3];
Manipulate[ListPlot[{
    {Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Array[r[#][t] &, robbers],
    {Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Array[c[#][t] &, cops]},
    Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Blue, PointSize[Medium]}, {Red, PointSize[Medium]}}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
    {t, 0, duration}]
```

[image]

### Numerical Instability

Because the equations are inherently non-linear, the numerical solutions are unstable. `NDSolve` may sometimes complain of "Maxium number of 10000 steps reached ...", which can be avoided by lowering the `PrecisionGoal` or raising `MaxSteps`.

Here we solve from the same initial positions, but use different `PrecisionGoal`s:

```
Clear[cLow, cHigh, rLow, rHigh]
SeedRandom[0]
Evaluate@{Array[cLow, cops], Array[rLow, robbers]} = 
    solveChase[cops, robbers, duration, PrecisionGoal -> 3];
SeedRandom[0]
Evaluate@{Array[cHigh, cops], Array[rHigh, robbers]} = 
    solveChase[cops, robbers, duration, PrecisionGoal -> 4, MaxSteps -> 100000];
```

And we pick the trajectories of robber and cop number 4. In both cases, the trajectories of low and high precisions initially coincide, but inevitably at some point they will split and go their separate ways. As a result these trajectories are only accurate for a very small duration of time.

```
ParametricPlot[{
    {Re[rLow[4][t]], Im[rLow[4][t]]},
    {Re[rHigh[4][t]], Im[rHigh[4][t]]},
    {Re[cLow[4][t]], Im[cLow[4][t]]},
    {Re[cHigh[4][t]], Im[cHigh[4][t]]}},
    {t, 0, duration}, 
    PlotStyle -> {
        {Thickness[0.02], LightGray}, {Dashed, Black},
        {Thickness[0.02], LightBlue}, {Dashed, Red}}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    PlotLegends -> {"robber low", "robber high", "cop low", "cop high"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very good and complete answer.

Comment: Actually, is there a better method to put walls there? Adding 1 cop each side is not natural, and they are running from walls.

Comment: Putting guards on walls is very easy to implement :) For a more "natural" wall, perhaps you can play with the `WhenEvent` conditions of `NDSolve`?

Answer (score 8):

Let's make `r[t]` and `c[t]` depend on time step `t`. Suppose we have 5 robbers and 3 cops, and their initial positions are:

```
r[0] = RandomReal[10, {5, 2}]
c[0] = RandomReal[10, {3, 2}]
```

Given the current position `x` of a robber and a list `y` of that of the cops, define the robber's next step (the arrow) to be:

```
step[x_, y_List] := Normalize@Sum[(x - y[[i]])/Norm[x - y[[i]]]^2, {i, Length[y]}]
```

The next position of the robbers and the cops are:

```
r[t_] := r[t] = r[t - 1] + (step[#, c[t - 1]] & /@ r[t - 1])
c[t_] := c[t] = c[t - 1] - (step[#, r[t - 1]] & /@ c[t - 1])
```

Note the opposite signs of the `step`, as robbers are running *away* from the cops and the cops are running *towards* the robbers. Memoization is used here to avoid recalculation. If you need to change the initial values then you have to `Clear[r, c]`. Now we can ask e.g.:

```
c[8][[2]]
(* {7.63022, 4.67586} *)
```