# NDSolve with different function lengths over time

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm working on a cops & robbers game, and there is one single event that is very very important, the event of *catching* someone. I'm trying to do when any robber is catched, delete it from the robbers array. I think it must be done with [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WhenEvent.html)

A cop catches a robber if the circles that define them are touching.

A visual representation can be seen [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40667/10682).

There is an array showing the initial positions of all (let's say *cops=5 and robbers=3*) the cops & robbers

The arrays are like this (the 0 is the time):

```
cops = 5; robbers = 3;
Array[c[#][0] &, cops]
Array[r[#][0] &, robbers]
```

The [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html) looks like this:

```
NDSolve[
 Join[
  Table[
   r[i]'[t] == v[r[i][t], b[r[i][t]]~Join~Array[c[#][t] &, cops], 2],
   {i, robbers}
   ],
  Table[
   c[i]'[t] == -v[c[i][t], Array[r[#][t] &, robbers], 4],
   {i, cops}
   ],
  (*initial positions*)
  Thread[
   Array[r[#][0] &, robbers] == {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}
   ],
  Thread[
   Array[c[#][0] &, cops] == {{6,5},{4,3},{2,1}}
   ]
  ],
 Array[c, cops]~Join~Array[r, robbers],
 {t, 0, 10},
 FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NDSolve]],
 Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}
]
```

I'm guessing to put something like:

```
Table[
    WhenEvent[
        catched[i]==True,
        Array[r[#][t] &, robbers]->
        Cases[
            Array[r[#][t] &, robbers],
            Except[
                r[i][t]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    {i,robbers}
]
```

But doesn't work, I'm guessing because `NDSolve` can't calculate with this method lists of functions that vary with time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't make `NDSolve` let you change the length of the solution vector either, but I can suggest a workaround. Placing the action `"StopIntegration"` in your `WhenEvent` can halt `NDSolve` at a critical event. You can then restart the integration after changing the equations however you like. Here's an example for a linear system that loses a dimension and changes its behavior when the first variable crosses zero.

```
f[x_?VectorQ, A_] := A.x;
T = \[Pi];
x0 = {1, 0};
stop = 0;
Do[
  A = Switch[i, 1, {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}, 2, {{-1}}];
  sol[i] = First@NDSolve[{
      x'[t] == f[x[t], A],
      x[stop] == x0, 
      WhenEvent[x[t][[1]] == 0, stop = t; "StopIntegration"]}, 
     x, {t, stop, T}];
  x0 = x[stop] /. sol[i];
  x0 = Rest[x0],{i,2}];
Show @@ Table[
  Plot[x[t] /. sol[i], Evaluate[Join[{t}, sol[i][[1, 2, 1, 1]]]],
   PlotRange -> {{0, T}, {-1, 1}}], {i, 2}]
```

Sorry, that last line is not very elegant. Also note, in this example I let the variable `x[t]` be a vector, rather than supplying several variables `x[i][t]`. The only trick to making this work is the conditional definition for `f`, which prevents symbolic evaluation of the integrand.